# Ionic 3 iOS app does not go beyond splashcreen

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been on the same spot for weeks now, my ionic 3 app for iOS does not go beyond the splash screen since i updated my system's ionic version to 4.

The android app is working fine.

Comment: any errors in xcode debug console?

Comment: Try removing the iOS platform and re-adding it. You may also need to check your plugins to see if any are outdated.

Comment: @SaEChowdary no errors shown